# getBeaconState() returns null, no matter what type of attachment I add to my beacon

Tags: android, bluetooth, snapshot, beacon

Setting my attachment details through Beacon dashboard. I keep getting: `getBeaconState("FILTER")` **null**. My goal is to just detect when a beacon is nearby for now. Any one form help me would be great!

I have already set up my virtual beacon as per eddystone format and it works perfectly (in beacon dashboard I see: The beacon is active and works correctly!) And have obviously set up my project on Google console and added same API keys to Advertiser and this(scanner) app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    List<BeaconState.TypeFilter> BEACON_TYPE_FILTERS = Arrays.asList(BeaconState.TypeFilter
            .with("alpine-shade-255114", "int"));

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        hasLocationPermission();
        addBeaconDetectorFence();
    }

    private void hasLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            return;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void addBeaconDetectorFence() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            return;
        }

        Awareness.getSnapshotClient(this).getBeaconState(BEACON_TYPE_FILTERS)
                .addOnSuccessListener(beaconResult -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Got beacon state");
                    if(beaconResult!=null){
                    BeaconState beaconState = beaconResult.getBeaconState();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got beacon state! " + beaconState,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not get beacon state");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not get beacon state!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
    }
}
```

So, when I debug, it enters `addOnSuccessListener` but `beaconState` is always **null**.

Comment: is the filter data correct? Just a step to debug, is it possible to remove filter and check for the beacon state?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `getBeaconState()` is only supported on device API level above 18.

If calling from a device running an earlier version(below API 18), `getStatus()` will return status like **API_NOT_AVAILABLE**.

Moreover, the `getBeaconState()` method requires an `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. Add this permission in  `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
Awareness.SnapshotApi.getBeaconState(mGoogleApiClient, BEACON_TYPE_FILTERS)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<BeaconStateResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull BeaconStateResult beaconStateResult) {
                        if (!beaconStateResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get beacon state.");
                            return;
                        }
                        BeaconState beaconState = beaconStateResult.getBeaconState();
                        // Get info from the BeaconState.
                    }
                });
```

In your code, you miss `onResult()` method. I hope it'll help you...!